# Why is Mathematica not simplifying eigenvalues?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, eigenvalues

For matrix `A = {{x*Exp[I*y], z}, {z, x*Exp[(-I)*y]}};`  , *Mathematica* yields the following eigenvalues:

```
 e1 = ((1/2)*(x + Exp^(2*I*y)*x - Sqrt[x^2 - 2*Exp^(2*I*y)*x^2 + Exp^(4*I*y)*x^2 + 
       4*Exp^(2*I*y)*z^2]))/Exp^(I*y)
 e2 = ((1/2)*(x + Exp^(2*I*y)*x + Sqrt[x^2 - 2*Exp^(2*I*y)*x^2 + Exp^(4*I*y)*x^2 + 
       4*Exp^(2*I*y)*z^2]))/Exp^(I*y)
```

But I know that  these eigenvalues have the simple form:

```
  e1 = x*Cos[y] - Sqrt[z^2 - (x*Sin[y])^2]; 
  e2 = x*Cos[y] + Sqrt[z^2 - (x*Sin[y])^2];
```

How to make *Mathematica* to yield the eigenvalues in this simple form?

Edit: All parameters $x,y,z$ are real and positive.

Comment: We probably need some conditions to get your form. For example, are all your parameters (x, y, z) real and what is their range of values?

Comment: Thanks @Hugh, yes all parameters are real and positive.

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to move the exp inside the sqrt and use the double angle trig rule.

```
A = {{x*Exp[I*y], z}, {z, x*Exp[(-I)*y]}}
{v1, v2} = Eigenvalues[A]
```

[image]

```
Expand[v1];
% /. any1_ + n_.*Exp[any2_]*Sqrt[any3_] :> any1 + n*Sqrt[Exp[any2]^2*any3];
Simplify@ExpToTrig[%];
% /. Cos[2*a_] :> 1 - 2 Sin[a]^2 // Simplify
```

[image]

```
Expand[v2];
% /. any1_ + n_.*Exp[any2_]*Sqrt[any3_] :> any1 + n*Sqrt[Exp[any2]^2*any3];
% /. Cos[2*a_] :> 1 - 2 Sin[a]^2 // Simplify
FullSimplify@ExpToTrig[%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Eigenvalues[{{x*Exp[I*y], z}, {z, x*Exp[(-I)*y]}} // ComplexExpand]//FullSimplify
```

> `{x Cos[y] - Sqrt[-(x^2/2) + z^2 + 1/2 x^2 Cos[2 y]],  x Cos[y] + Sqrt[-(x^2/2) + z^2 + 1/2 x^2 Cos[2 y]]}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

A = {{x*Exp[I*y], z}, {z, x*Exp[(-I)*y]}};

ev = Assuming[{x, y, z} ∈ PositiveReals,
   Eigenvalues[A] // Simplify];

ev2 = Assuming[{x, y, z} ∈ PositiveReals,
  Eigenvalues[A] //
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
   FullSimplify]

(* {x Cos[y] - E^(-I y) Sqrt[E^(2 I y) (z^2 - x^2 Sin[y]^2)], 
 x Cos[y] + E^(-I y) Sqrt[E^(2 I y) (z^2 - x^2 Sin[y]^2)]} *)
```

You apparently want to assume that

```
eqn = E^(-I*y) Sqrt[E^(2*I*y)*(z^2 - x^2*Sin[y]^2)] == 
  Sqrt[z^2 - x^2*Sin[y]^2];
```

However, looking for a counter-example

```
ce = FindInstance[{! eqn, {x, y, z} ∈ PositiveReals}, {x, y, z}] // 
  Quiet

(* {{x -> 1117/10, y -> 133/10, z -> 294/5}} *)
```

Verifying that this is a counter-example

```
eqn /. ce[[1]]

(* False *)
```

numerically,

```
(List @@ eqn) /. ce[[1]] // N[#, 15] & // Chop

(* {-46.2195312683779 I, 46.2195312683779 I} *)
```

For a second counter-example,

```
ce2 = FindInstance[{! (eqn /. x -> 1), {y, z} ∈ PositiveReals}, {y, 
    z}] // Quiet

(* {{y -> 347/10, z -> 149/10}} *)

eqn /. x -> 1 /. ce2[[1]]

(* False *)

(List @@ eqn) /. x -> 1 /. ce2[[1]] // N[#, 15] & // Chop

(* {-14.8993233477646, 14.8993233477646} *)
```

Consequently, `ev2` is the simplified form.